# python utf-8 encoding throws UnicodeDecodeError despite "errors = 'replace' "

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

I'm trying to write out some text and encode it as utf-8 where possible, using the following code:

```
outf.write((lang_name + "," + (script_name or "") + "\n").encode("utf-8", errors='replace'))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode 
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

I thought the `errors='replace'` part of my encode call would handle that?

fwiw, I'm just opening the file with

```
outf = open(outfile, 'w')
```

without explicitly declaring the encoding.

```
print repr(outf)
```

produces:

```
<open file 'myfile.csv', mode 'w' at 0x000000000315E930>
```

I separated out the write statement into a separate concatenation, encoding, and file write:

```
outstr = lang_name + "," + (script_name or "") + "\n"
encoded_outstr = outstr.encode("utf-8", errors='replace')
outf.write(encoded_outstr)
```

It is the concatenation that throws the exception.

The string are, via `print repr(foo)`

```
lang_name: 'G\xc4\x81ndh\xc4\x81r\xc4\xab'
script_name: u'Kharo\u1e63\u1e6dh\u012b'
```

Further detective work reveals that I can concatenate either one of those with a plain ascii string without any difficulty - it's putting them both into the same string that is breaking things.

Comment: What is `script_code` and `script_name` here? You have a **decoding** error, not encoding, so one or both are bytestrings, not `unicode` objects.

Comment: `.encode("utf-8")` on a Unicode string will always work, since all Unicode points can be represented as UTF8, so in that case `errors='replace'` is superfluous.

Comment: Next, what is `outf` here? How did you open that object? That your code tries to decode a bytestring *as CP1252* is suspicious. For implicit decodings that'd mean you used `sys.setdefaultencoding()` (a big no-no), but if `outf` is not a regular Python 2 file object but instead a `codecs` or `io` file object that'd explain the exception as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I showed how I opened outf.  script_code and script_name are strings scraped from a webpage.

Comment: I think that if he puts `s = script_code + "," + (script_name or "") + "\n"` on the line before, that that will raise the exception.

Comment: @PurpleVermont: what does `print repr(script_code), repr(script_name)` produce? Did you use `from codecs import open` or `from io import open`?

Comment: There's no `sys.setdefaultencoding()` explicitly in my code.  `outf` should be a normal python file object

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: only if they used `sys.setdefaultencoding('cp1252')` somewhere else. Otherwise I expect ASCII to be used.

Comment: @PurpleVermont: so `print repr(outf)` produces?

Comment: @MartijnPieters <open file 'wikipediaLangScripts.csv', mode 'w' at 0x000000000315E930> (added to the question)

Comment: @PurpleVermont: can you break down the expressions? Put your string concatenation on a separate line (store result in a variable), then next line do the encode, then next line do the `outf.write()`. Then include the *full traceback*. We also asked you for the values of the `script_*` variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far guys.  I have to take off for a meeting, will respond to the other stuff after.  I lost track of which loop iteration broke it (it works fine for hundreds of prior values) so I don't have the values of the script_ variables right now, but will rerun while in my meeting and get those also

Comment: @RemcoGerlich you were right

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem is that you are concatenating the bytestring `'G\xc4\x81ndh\xc4\x81r\xc4\xab'` and the Unicode string `u'Kharo\u1e63\u1e6dh\u012b'`.

To be able to do that, Python 2.7 tries to decode the bytestring using its default encoding, to turn it into Unicode. Your default encoding is cp1252 instead of ASCII, for reasons I can't know from here, but anyway it fails just like it would had it been ASCII because that string is UTF8.

Your best solution is probably to make sure that this doesn't happen, by changing the way the variables get those values in the first place.

If you can't, since you are encoding to UTF8 on the next line anyway, it's probably easiest to only encode script_name:

```
encoded_outstr = lang_name + b"," + (script_name.encode('utf-8') or b"") + b"\n"
```

Note that I used `b","` to explicitly make those string literals bytestrings and not Unicode strings; if you are using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` for Python 3 compatibility, then they are Unicode by default and the problem would just occur again.

Comment: the problem is that I don't think the encodings are consistent for every iteration of the loop (!)  Is there a programmatic way to test for what the encoding is?  I kind of think that that's an open research question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When you concatenate a byte string and a Unicode string, Python 2 attempts to convert the byte string to Unicode first. If the byte string contains any non-ASCII characters in the range of `\x80` to `\xff`, the automatic conversion will fail with the error you show. Notice that it says `can't decode`, not `can't encode` - this shows that the error did *not* occur in your call to `encode`.

The solution is to `decode` the byte string into Unicode yourself, using the proper code page, so that all the inputs to the concatenation are Unicode strings.

```
outstr = lang_name.decode("utf-8") + u"," + (script_name or u"") + u"\n"
```